# useLoader() throws TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /lut/F-6800-STD.cube

Tags: next.js13, react-three-fiber

I was recreating the setup for the prism sample https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nextjs-prism-j3ycvl
using Next.js, and it turns out that the framework is having a hard time to parsing the .cube file

```
export default function App() { 
const texture = useLoader( LUTCubeLoader, "/lut/F-6800-STD.cube" ); 
return ...
}
```

[public folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDVIi.png)

Any solution for this matter?
I recreated the sample using vite framework and everything works fine there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disabling the ssr fixed the issue
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#with-no-ssr

Shut out to Cody dev from the r3f team!